# Starting a systemd service with privileges

Tags: systemd

I would like systemd to manage the [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/) monitor, so I wrote a service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor source files for changes

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tup monitor -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tup stop
WorkingDirectory=/some/dir
StandardOutput=journal+console
StandardError=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Whereas starting the monitor manually works, trying to do it with systemd fails with the following error:

```
setpgid: Operation not permitted
tup error: Unable to set process group for tup's subprocesses.
```

The error originates in [this file](https://github.com/gittup/tup/blob/master/src/tup/server/master_fork.c) and seems to be due to systemd not giving the process the capabilities it needs, so I went further:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor source files for changes

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tup monitor -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tup stop
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID
WorkingDirectory=/some/dir
StandardOutput=journal+console
StandardError=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Still, it doesn't work.

How can I tell systemd to keep the permissions tup requires?

Comment: Does `root` own the TUP binary/script and its resources?

Comment: @PraveenP Yes, `root` owns the program and its resources (it's installed via package manager).

Comment: If it is installed through package manager, it should have service file already. Try `service tup status`?

Comment: No, it hasn't got a service unit: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/tup/files/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

systemd does not restrict any permissions on services by default, so I don’t think that’s the problem. The `setpgid(2)` manpage mentions three possible conditions for `EPERM`, though:

> An attempt was made to move a process into a process group in a different session, or to change the process group ID of one of the children of the calling process and the child was in a different session, or to change the process group ID of a session leader (`setpgid()`, `setpgrp()`).

I think the third one is the most likely cause of the error: `tup` probably expects to be run from a shell, in which case the shell would be the session leader and `tup` tries to establish its own process group, but systemd places each service in its own session as part of setting up a clean execution environment for the service (see also `daemon(7)`), so that step fails.

Unless you can somehow disable that step in `tup` (it doesn’t need to `fork`, either, or do a number of other things which systemd makes unnecessary), I think the only workaround would be an ugly hack:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/tup monitor -f'
```

With this, the session leader will be the shell, not `tup`, so the `setpgid` should work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor source files for changes
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tup monitor -f
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tup stop
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID
WorkingDirectory=/some/dir
StandardOutput=journal+console
StandardError=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've added `After=network.target`, this will make sure TUP service starts after the network is fully active and avoid the service failing due to network issues

Comment: But tup has nothing to do with any network, what it needs is the ability to call [setpgid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html).

Comment: I believe `WantedBy` needs some sort of `After` dependency to work. You can try adding `setpgid` as `After` option and see. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files#ftn.idm140212702055552

Comment: There is no `setpgid` service. `setpgid` is a system call. The problem is not in the dependencies whatsoever, it's in systemd taking away some capabilities which tup needs.

Comment: Systemd shouldn't take away any privileges as all services ran as `root`, there is no higher privilege than that

Comment: Could you post the full logs when you run `service tup status` please?

Comment: I already posted the full logs: `setpgid: Operation not permitted`, `tup error: Unable to set process group for tup's subprocesses`. Unfortunately, that's all it says.